# boost::in_place taking arguments as const refs

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have a class where the constructor takes parameter as reference. For eg.

```
class A
{
    A(Tracer& t) : m_t(t) { }
  private:
     Tracer& m_t;
};
```

I have this `class A` as boost::optional and want to construct it only when needed. If I use boost::in_place to construct it. Since `boost::in_place` takes the parameters as const_refs, I had to modify the signature of the constructor to

```
A(const Tracer& t) : m_t(const_cast<Tracer&>(t)  { }
```

is there any other way of passing the object by reference ?

The s/w limitation is boost 1.4.3, VS2010.

**EDIT**: The class is not copy-constructible and assignable as well. I haven't showed that in the sample class mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

struct Tracer
{
    Tracer() = default;

    Tracer(const Tracer&) = delete;
    Tracer(Tracer&&) = delete;
    Tracer& operator=(const Tracer&) = delete;
    Tracer& operator=(Tracer&&) = delete;
};

class A
{
public: // Note: I had to add this.
    A(Tracer& t) : m_t(t) { }
private:
     Tracer& m_t;
};

int main()
{
    Tracer tracer;
    boost::optional<A> x;

    x = boost::in_place(boost::ref(tracer));
}
```

`boost::ref` returns a `boost::reference_wrapper`, which models a reference as a value.

Comment: I don't have the compiler at hand now. But I did try this and got a compilation error. May be has to do with something else. If you are 100% sure then I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jagannath: I've updated the example to emphasize changes I made and the noncopyability of `Tracer`. I'm using g++ 4.8.1.